# Change this sub inputs each as a cell to a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to modify this sub to instead of accepting a cell one at a time, one from source and to one destination, to accepting a range of cells, a source range and a destination range.

My goal is to call this Sub to copy just the data validations from an input range of cells and paste them into another range of cells by calling this Sub. This Sub is meant to be able to be called by other Subs (and perhaps functions too) so it needs to be reusable. Can anyone shed some light on this issue for me please?

The code I would like to modify is:

```
Sub CopyValidation(ByRef rngSourceCell As Range, ByRef rngTargetCell As Range)
    With rngTargetCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=rngSourceCell.Validation.Type, _
            AlertStyle:=rngSourceCell.Validation.AlertStyle, _
            Operator:=rngSourceCell.Validation.Operator, Formula1:=rngSourceCell.Validation.Formula1, Formula2:=rngSourceCell.Validation.Formula2
        .ErrorMessage = rngSourceCell.Validation.ErrorMessage
        .ErrorTitle = rngSourceCell.Validation.ErrorTitle
        .IgnoreBlank = rngSourceCell.Validation.IgnoreBlank
        .IMEMode = rngSourceCell.Validation.IMEMode
        .InCellDropdown = rngSourceCell.Validation.InCellDropdown
        .InputMessage = rngSourceCell.Validation.InputMessage
        .InputTitle = rngSourceCell.Validation.InputTitle
        .ShowError = rngSourceCell.Validation.ShowError
        .ShowInput = rngSourceCell.Validation.ShowInput
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to setup each parameter separately.  Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r1 = Range("A1:A10")
    Set r2 = Range("B1:B10")
    r1.Copy
    r2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
End Sub
```

Even your single cell routine can use this:

```
Sub CopyValidation(ByRef rngSourceCell As Range, ByRef rngTargetCell As Range)
    rngSourceCell.Copy
    rngTargetCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
End Sub
```

In fact, the second routine can handle both single cells and multi-cell ranges *(as long as the ranges are isomorphic)*

Comment: I take it isomorphic you mean that they are in a group rectangular to each other, as if you were to drag your mouse to select the cells?

Comment: @DavidS.  Yes.............either from one rectangle to another of the same dimensions, or from one section of a row to another section of a row, or from one section of a column to another section of a column, or from a single cell to a rectangle, etc..................just like any other copy/pastespecial.